# How to create flowchart in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, flowchart

I am getting raw `json` data.

I want to create a `flowchart` from that data.

I tried with raphael and flowchart js

http://jsfiddle.net/hemantmalpote/fbmwket8/4/

I want hold over every control(condition box,... etc), i.e
i want to handle click event in controls and perform some action.

Is there any way to get events in flowchar js Or
Is there any plugin or anybody have sample which will create flow chart using json and allow to handle click events in controls.

Comment: What is the format of the JSON?

Comment: You can take a look at draw2d - http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/

Comment: It may helpful to you.. http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen: Json will contain all the data like i show in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with Mxdraw js plugin, we can customize based on your needs.
https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/diagrameditor.html

The following are related to your needs

```
Graph Editor - Fully functional diagram editor and drawing application.
mxDraw - Web 2.0-style diagram editor and drawing application.
mxProcess - Process editor with a fancy stylesheet and user interface.
mxWorkflow - BPMN workflow editor with various example diagrams.
mxWorkflow/Layout - BPMN workflow editor with automatic layout.(Experimental)
```